# Поиск Эйлерова цикла в ориентированном графе

Tags: алгоритм

Каким алгоритмом можно найти в ориентированном графе Эйлеров цикл ? Я нашел только алгоритм Флёри, но он не очень эффективный.

Comment: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/euler_path

Comment: в этой статье говорится об алгоритме для неориентированного графа.

Comment: @NEvOI, прочтите там ветку с самым первым комментарием

Comment: я правильно понял, что для того что бы в ориентированном графе был Эйлеров цикл, необходимо и достаточно что бы у каждой вершины, степень исхода была равна степени захода ? Т.е. если это не так то цикла в графе точно нет.

Answer (score 2):

Хирхольцер свой линейный алгоритм успел придумать и умер ещё до Флёри.

Проверили эйлеровость.

Выбрали вершину, пошли по рёбрам, пока не вернулись в неё же (мы в неё вернёмся, т.к. исходящая степень и входящая одинаковы для эйлерова графа).

Пройденный путь записываем. Если в пути есть вершина с непосещёнными рёбрами, повторяем для неё и прицепляем новый путь к старому. Так делаем, пока есть непосещённые рёбра.